# sed wildcard and back reference

Tags: sed, wildcard

I have a text log file that I need to add some basic html like stuff (to match decades of older logs).

It basically looks like this in all lines

```
<constant> <various> text
```

and should transform to this in each line

```
<font color="#7a40b0">constant:</font><font color="#0000fc">various:</font> text
```

`constant` always remains the same, `various` changes (these are usernames, could be anything, e.g. F0oBar 1)

I tried

```
sed 's|'\<constant\>\ \<'.*'\>'|'\<font\ color\=\"#7a40b0\"\>constant:\</font\>\<font\ color\=\"#0000fc\"\>\1:\</font\>'|g'
```

but this just returns

```
<font color="#7a40b0">constant:</font><font color="#0000fc">1:</font>
```

I tried searching on how to make the back reference work but I'm sure now I'm messing up the wildcard. As soon as I use parenthesis, brackets and/or ^ stuff breaks (the regex doesn't match anymore).
I've used https://sed.js.org to give me a visual help so I hope this gave me correct feedback.

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Not everything with <> is XML/HTML, it's a log file that just has user names in <name>, no xml structure whatsover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's|<([^ ]*)> <([^ ]*)>|<font color="#7a40b0">\1:</font><font color="#0000fc">\2:</font>|' input_file
<font color="#7a40b0">constant:</font><font color="#0000fc">various:</font> text
```